# What is the breakdown at the end of shows called?

Tags: composition, styles

I have found that towards the end of rock shows the song ends and then there is some amount of random noise produced before the show ends. Usually, it is when the singer says goodnight and goodbye to the audience. What is this called? Is it a breakdown or an outro? What would you call it, find an example towards the end of the given song.

Comment: I suspect this is related to the thing that bands do to end single songs- A quick roll-off followed by a crash with a big visual wind-up- cueing the band to hit that last note together.

Comment: I'd suggest putting your video start time later.

Comment: I call it cacophony - from the Greek - kakos (bad), and phony (sound).

Comment: You mean, something like this? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ts7K4yCP5tI#t=3m43s

Comment: 'A Day in the Life' (The Beatles) seems to have a similar ending.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I’ve encountered a few band leaders that represent this as “Trash“ in the chord chart. It’s sometimes tied to a chord, as in “and then we end with a trash on C,” meaning “imagine a fermata in which everyone improvises over the base of a C chord, without a unified sense of pulse or rhythm.” It might be a reference to the idea of [“trashing” gear at the end of a show](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrument_destruction)?

On further googling, it seems like this might be short for "[trash can ending](https://blog.discmakers.com/2014/07/power-of-a-trash-can-ending/)"; that phrase gets several hits including drum tutorial videos.

Comment: Because of the underline in the link, I initially read "trashino" rather than "trashing". **Trashino** n. Brief but chaotic ending to a song. See also **trashing**.

Answer (score 5):

The video game series *Rock Band* terms this a "Big Rock Ending". (See https://rockband.fandom.com/wiki/Big_Rock_Ending, https://wiki.scorehero.com/BigRockEnding, and https://www.reddit.com/r/Rockband/comments/8dxtl7/list_of_big_rock_ending_lengths/ for uses of this term.)

For what it's worth, TVTropes also calls this a "Big Rock Ending" according to https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BigRockEnding.

Answer (score 3):

In the bands I've played in, we just called a "breakdown", or even less formally, we'd just say, "okay, everyone go crazy here". "Breakdown" is the most common term I've heard.

An outro is usually more structured, and a tighter part of the song structure, although it doesn't have to be either one.

The video demonstrates an extreme version of something jazz groups have done for a long time: the band holds a final chord, while a soloist and/or the drummer go nuts, and then the director cues a final hit.

As one example amongst many, here is the final chord of "Tank" by Yoko Kanno (theme from "Cowboy Bebop"):

Comment: "Breakdown" is already an established term for a different section of a song [(a typically instrumental groove section)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PbWZU9tuzb4), so I wouldn't use that word without qualification.

Comment: I've heard studio producers refer to the final hit as a "button".